# Assistance with splitting data frame to new columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string, python-re

I'm having trouble splitting a data frame by _ and creating new columns from it.

The original strand

```
AMAT_0000006951_10Q_20200726_Item1A_excerpt.txt    as section
```

my current code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(myList,columns=['section','text'])
#df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace('•','')
df['section'] = df['section'].str.replace('Item1A', 'Filing Section: Risk Factors')
df['section'] = df['section'].str.replace('Item2_', 'Filing Section: Management Discussion and Analysis')
df['section'] = df['section'].str.replace('excerpt.txt', '').str.replace(r'\d{10}_|\d{8}_', '')
df.to_csv("./SECParse.csv", encoding='utf-8-sig', sep=',',index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
section                                 text
AMAT_10Q_Filing Section: Risk Factors_  The COVID-19 pandemic and global measures taken in response 
                                        thereto have adversely impacted, and may continue to adversely 
                                        impact, Applied’s operations and financial results.
AMAT_10Q_Filing Section: Risk Factors_  The COVID-19 pandemic and measures taken in response by 
                                        governments and businesses worldwide to contain its spread, 
                                        
AMAT_10Q_Filing Section: Risk Factors_  The degree to which the pandemic ultimately impacts Applied’s 
                                        financial condition and results of operations and the global 
                                        economy will depend on future developments beyond our control
```

I would really like to split up 'section' in a way that puts it in new columns based on '_'
I've tried so many different variations of regex to split 'section' and all of them either gave me headings with no fill or they added columns after section and text, which isn't useful. I should also add theres going to be around 100,000 observations.

Desired result:

```
Ticker  Filing type  Section                       Text
AMAT    10Q          Filing Section: Risk Factors  The COVID-19 pandemic and global measures taken in response
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always know the number of splits, you can do something like:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ "a": [ "test_a_b", "test2_c_d" ] })

# Split column by "_"
items = df["a"].str.split("_")

# Get last item from splitted column and place it on "b"
df["b"] = items.apply(list.pop)

# Get next last item from splitted column and place it on "c"
df["c"] = items.apply(list.pop)

# Get final item from splitted column and place it on "d"
df["d"] = items.apply(list.pop)
```

That way, the dataframe will turn into

```py
           a  b  c      d
0   test_a_b  b  a   test
1  test2_c_d  d  c  test2
```

Since you want the columns to be on a certain order, you can reorder the dataframe's columns as below:

```py
>>> df = df[[ "d", "c", "b", "a" ]]
>>> df
       d  c  b          a
0   test  a  b   test_a_b
1  test2  c  d  test2_c_d
```

Comment: Hey Marco, when I try this the added columns appear behind the columns section and text

Comment: You can reorder the columns after inserting them. I will edit my answer to include such reordering.

Comment: wish I could upvote your answer - everything works perfectly now - appreciate it!

Comment: @xSuperAnnuated I'm glad that helped!